# The flag menu moves down every time you navigate

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flag-dialog

Using Google Chrome 61.0.3163.100, every time you jump from one submenu to another submenu, the window position goes down in the Y axis.

You can reproduce it easily by doing:

1. Click on flag button.
2. Click on "should be closed..."
3. Click again on "Flagging" (top left corner).
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3.

Note: It happens on every submenu. I chose "should be closed..." just as an example.

Comment: I repro this in Safari as well. It must be a *very* new bug. I didn't notice it just a few hours ago.

Comment: Looks like it is shifting 120px with every iteration.

Comment: Also happens on Firefox 56.

Comment: Also happens in Safari iOS 7.1.1

Comment: Confirmed on Version 63.0.3239.18 (Official Build) beta too

Comment: Also happens on "a duplicate..." (for step 2)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It happens for every submenu. I just chose one of them for the steps.

Comment: Also confirmed on Chrome 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build)

Comment: I hope people don't accidentally flag this post while trying to duplicate (I almost did...)

Comment: Also happens in IE11 (11.674.15063.0).

Comment: Happens on every menu except for Closing>Off-Topic (Chrome)

Comment: For me it also jumps to the right, not only down.

Comment: @Adriaan I can't reproduce it moving to the right.

Comment: @lilezek interestingly enough clicking "flagging" moves it to the lower left, and clicking "Should be closed" moves it to the lower right. Could be something with my window size; I'm on Chrome 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: [Also reported (and answered) on MSE.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303599/the-flag-modal-keeps-going-down)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed earlier - see [The "Flag" modal keeps going down](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303599/the-flag-modal-keeps-going-down) for details!

Comment: Well, technically not earlier, as I my post was wrote before his!

Comment: Earlier than right now :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't understand the meaning of this answer.