# When going to second dialog while flagging, the modal moves right

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was flagging a question earlier, and when I clicked on `should be closed...` to go to the next dialog, I noticed the entire modal moved right, and not just slightly. I tested on other SE sites, and they did not have the same issue.

Even worse when you try to go back to main flagging dialog, it keeps moving right, so everytime the dialog gets changed, it gets moved further right.

[image]

Comment: cross site duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311115/flag-dialog-jumps-around

Comment: It may be part of the new attitude that we are cultivating. Closing question can be perceived as unwelcoming, so it makes sense to make it slightly harder. :P

Comment: @rene: ...which appears to be a dupe of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303599/the-flag-modal-keeps-going-down, which I guess makes this one a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358609/the-flag-menu-moves-down-every-time-you-navigate. The only difference is that, with the new left sidebar, the dialog is now moving sideways, too.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen old one is not relevant, this is a new bug, looking at css classes, look at comments on Rene's link

Comment: @Alec: The CSS classes seem like a red herring to me. If you don't believe that just because I say so, try installing [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) and see if [the JS patch for the older issue](https://github.com/vyznev/soup/blob/68cdb600b9a0e4901790585259216567ed548e33/SOUP.user.js#L1590) included in it fixes this bug. (It does for me.)

Answer (score 2):

Fixed in the next build. This has been broken [for a while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303599/the-flag-modal-keeps-going-down), but until now, it was only a couple of pixels. With the new unified layout however, the difference between the document and the popup's positioning parent got much bigger, making this bug much more obvious (and annoying).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen No, I [did exactly what you suggested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWPho.png). I just wish I had read your answer *before* doing that, because I wouldn't have had to debug it myself :)